# Soundcloud API with private player (not working)

Tags: api, soundcloud, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm using the API wrapper Ruby Soundcloud.

I'm able to retrieve some soundcloud sounds & playlists info as well as update it.

Problem 1:
The "embeddable_by" doesn't update (it always stays at none even when I'm updating to "all" for example).

Problem 2:
If I set a sound to sharing:private (with embeddable_by:all), I get a "The sound can't be played outside of Soundcloud".

I do use the secret token in my url:

```
  <iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<%= @audiofile.soundcloud_url %>%3Fsecret_token%3D<%= @sc_token %>&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe><br />
```

What's weird is that if I'm getting the embed code from the Soundcloud website (on the sound page), it works. Also magically it starts working with my custom embed code! Isn't it weird?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "streamable" must be set to "true" to make it work :/